# Adding Metada and Options to S3 Objects when uploading a directory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am successfully uploading folders to S3 using `->uploadDirectory()`.  Several hundred folders have 100's, or 1,000's of images contained within them with so using `PutObject()` for each file hardly seemed to make sense.  The upload works, and all goes well, **but the ACL, StorageClass, and metadata is *not* being included** in the upload.

According to the docs at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#uploading-a-directory-to-a-bucket , the following code *should* accomplished this.  It is further documented with the `putObject()` function that is also cited.

I can find no examples of this function using anything but a directory and bucket, so fail to see what might be wrong with it.  Any ideas why the data in `$options` is being ignored?

```
$aws = Aws::factory('config.php');
$s3 = $aws->get('S3');
$dir = 'c:\myfolder\myfiles';
$bucket = 'mybucket;
$keyPrefix = "ABC/myfiles/";
$options = array(
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
    'Metadata'=> array(
        'MyVal1'=>'Something',
        'MyVal2'=>'Something else'
    )
);

$result = $s3->uploadDirectory($dir, $bucket, $keyPrefix, $options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters to provide to `putObject` or `createMultipartUpload` should be in the `params` option, not provided as top-level values in the options array. Try declaring your options as follows:

```
$options = array(
    'params' => array(
        'ACL' => 'public-read',
        'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
        'Metadata'=> array(
            'MyVal1'=>'Something',
            'MyVal2'=>'Something else',
        ),
    ),
);
```